# Why is $K[T_1, \ldots, T_n] / (f)$ integral where $f$ is a monic polynomial in $K[T_n]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a filed, and $K[T_1, \ldots, T_n]$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables, and $f$ be a monic polynomial in $K[T_n]$. We have a natural ring extension $K[T_1, \ldots, T_{n - 1}] \to K[T_1, \ldots, T_n] / (f)$ and want to show that this ring extension is integral. I might be missing something here, but I find it hard to believe that this is true. Suppose the degree of $f$ is $m$, then take $T_{n}^{m - 1} \in K[T_1, \ldots, T_n] / (f)$. How is this element integral? How to prove the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if we write $f(T_n)=T_n^r+a_{r-1}T_n^{r-1}+...+a_1T_n+a_0$ where $a_0, a_1,..., a_{r-1}\in K[T_1,...,T_{n-1}]$ then the coset $T_n+(f)$ is clearly a root of the following monic polynomial:

$x^r+(a_{r-1}+(f))x^{r-1}+...+(a_1+(f))x+(a_0+(f))\in K[T_1,...,T_{n-1}][x]$

This means $T_n+(f)$ is an integral element over $K[T_1,...,T_{n-1}]$.

Also, for $1\leq i\leq n-1$, the coset $T_i+(f)$ is the root of $x-(T_i+(f))\in K[T_1,...,T_{n-1}][x]$, and so an integral element as well. Since sums and products of integral elements are again integral it follows that the whole extension is integral.